# Is there any way to import a Cell number into a URL with =IMPORTXML function on google sheets?

Tags: html, xml, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

**Im trying to figure out wallet balances on google sheets with the =IMPORTXML function**

**I have a list of wallet addresses in column  A and trying to get Wallet Balances on column B**

**Im using the website snowtrace.io to look at wallet balances**

**So A1-A10 consists of these addresses**

```
0x01e083E449230CE8106cEb0085e723B120F4F23b

0x48148d8F9934937e6C0a9d8D069E5dD832cd4c76

0x1d21E96710Cf7180aDe9780437D5EFa0351daFA9

0x599127561Fe9A761Ed7a1b63A515225412C76299

0xC3987A2D88cb627aaeEAb059F93F6f063816a236

0x4E2A7d0e465D8d38aA5A1852D438e60b5832C1b4

0x76790C74aba4A30308041b8e9fD81bD3DDD2fD35

0x7C34d8280b264df11a5D33a15943b249BeFF52Cf

0xf818D2464C18FCB17ea481aaa9098CF92C3A44B5

0x2bDE88c5E313808BB3349258d2a705dfd5406376
```

**B1-B4 Would look something like this**

```
=IMPORTXML("https://snowtrace.io/address/0x01e083e449230ce8106ceb0085e723b120f4f23b","/html/body/div[1]/main/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]")
=IMPORTXML("https://snowtrace.io/address/0x48148d8F9934937e6C0a9d8D069E5dD832cd4c76","/html/body/div[1]/main/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]")
=IMPORTXML("https://snowtrace.io/address/0x1d21E96710Cf7180aDe9780437D5EFa0351daFA9","/html/body/div[1]/main/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]")
=IMPORTXML("https://snowtrace.io/address/0x599127561Fe9A761Ed7a1b63A515225412C76299","/html/body/div[1]/main/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]")
```

So I was wondering if there was a way to switch out the address in the URL and use the value from cells A1-A10 into something like =IMPORTXML("https://snowtrace.io/address/**"&A1)"**,"/html/body/div[1]/main/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]"), instead of =IMPORTXML("https://snowtrace.io/address/0x01e083e449230ce8106ceb0085e723b120f4f23b","/html/body/div[1]/main/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for one cell:

```
="https://snowtrace.io/address/"&A1
```

for array:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA("https://snowtrace.io/address/"&A1:A10)
```

note that `IMPORTXML` is not supported under `ARRAYFORMULA`

Comment: So theres no way to import a balance using IMPORTXML?

Comment: @Cody its possible to do only this: `=IMPORTXML("https://snowtrace.io/address/"&A1, "/html/body/div[1]/main/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]")`